# How to update Magento's Downloadable Product on existing order

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

There is one really weird thing about Magento that I can't figure out, and I have a hard time believing the functionality would not be built in so before I start hunting down extensions I thought I'd ask here because searching for an answer hasn't worked.

If someone orders a downloadable product, and we end up updating that file either via ftp or by uploading a new one in magento, how do you get it to reflect the new file in the customer's order? It still downloads the old file, probably through some sort of cache

Comment: You have to override order model and update the value of product_id in sales_flat_order_item

Comment: Thanks, weird that there is no way to just do this in magento